# Class Not Found Exception java applet

Tags: java, eclipse, class, applet, classnotfoundexception

I started learning Java a couple of weeks ago and I saw a tutorial about applets. I then tried creating my own applet but I have come across some errors.

First off: I'm trying to display on my browser the words "Hello world", pretty simple stuff. I created a class on eclipse called `HelloWorldApplet` and this is the code I put in:

```
package demetz;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HelloWorldApplet extends Applet
{
   public void paint (Graphics g)
   {
      g.drawString ("Hello World", 25, 50);
   }
}
```

Then, I created a basic HTML file on notepad++, this is the code that I put in:

```html
<html>
<title>The Hello, World Applet</title>
<hr>
<applet code="HelloWorldApplet.class" width="320" height="120">
If your browser was Java-enabled, a "Hello, World"
message would appear here.
</applet>
<hr>
</html>
```

Then, I uploaded both files to my web page and when I try to open the page my applet wont load, instead it will only display a message at the top left corner saying: "Error. Click for details"
When I click it, a message box appears in the middle of my screen saying

```
ClassNotFoundException
demetz.HelloWorldApplet
```

I have no idea what to do, I'm not very experienced in java, so i don't know many java terms, so if you post an answer please make it very detailed.
How do i solve this?

Comment: Have you tried these solutions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/problemsindex.html ?

Comment: In java, package names imply a corresponding directory structure. So `demetz.HelloWorldApplet` should be placed in `demetz/HelloworldApplet.class`. I recommend that you first get it to work without specifying a package.

Comment: Daniel, i have tried that, it did'nt work. Klas Lindback, what do you mean one should be placed into another?

Comment: @Demetz i think if it has a package then it should be a `JAR` file, so as @Klas said, first make it without a package, then move a step forward

Comment: For starters.. `code="HelloWorldApplet.class"` should be `code="demetz.HelloWorldApplet"`  Note that the HTMNL then should be in a directory along with a `demetz` directory that stores the `HelloWorldApplet.class` ..

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).